# Error while accessing Boost interprocess Shared Memory Region using Apache web interface

Tags: php, c++, boost

This refers to my previous question in detail .....

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086881/pblm-in-runing-exec-using-action-in-php

I am trying to access shared memory region (Boost Inter-process) from web page.

**Test_Program.cpp**

```
   vector<std::string> results;   
   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   try
   {
      managed_shared_memory segment(open_only,GetSharedMemoryName());
      typedef map< char_string,char_string, std::less<char_string>,  map_value_type_allocator> complex_map_type;
      complex_map_type *MyMap = segment.find<complex_map_type>("MyMap").first;
      void_allocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());
      std::pair<complex_map_type::iterator, complex_map_type::iterator> ppp;
      char_string cs(ConvertTolowercase(Keyword).c_str(), alloc_inst);
```

//Keyword that exist in MyMap already checked but cannot be found.

```
      if(MyMap->count(cs) != 0)
      {
        cout << "Keyword Found\n";
      }
   }
   catch(...)
   {
      shared_memory_object::remove(GetSharedMemoryName());
      throw;
   }
```

When i run this program online it works but when i run this program through web using following script it cannot access boost shared region. May i know where i am wrong.

Web Page code:

**localhost/run.php**

```
<?php 
    system('./Kw "WASH5P" '); 
?>
```

Comment: this is highly likely a permissions issue (the apache worker might have restricted permissions, or runs as a user that doesn't have access to this /dev/shm or this particular shared memory area)

Comment: I have installed apache on my local pc so i have full permission. Do i need to change something? Pls help me as i am in great need.

Comment: It's not about how much permissions _you_ /can/ have. It's about the permissions that the apache worker (child) process doesn't have. Yes, you need to change something because it's not working. (I don't know what to change. I gave you my hint so you can start figuring it out. Maybe you can find out what user the apache server is running as? Often this is `www-data`, or `httpd` etc.)

Comment: I checked apache server the file produced is www-data .....

Comment: This question is different from other question as i found it difficult to troubleshoot C++ boost shared memory access problem. So i am parallely trying accessing shared region from PHP which is diffault supported by Apache. So better will be compatibility.

Comment: That's a _huge_ assumption. The compatibility will obviously **not** be better since sharing memory between C++ processes is hap-hazard enough already. But, you know, I can see your point about this being a different question. I'd say they were both **[X/Y problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)** for the same, real, problem. You can ask a mod to undupe-vote if you wish, I won't object.

Comment: I could solve this problem by chancing apache permision. Thanks for help

Comment: Cheers. I'm glad you were able to figure it out.