# How to read map in php web application written using Boost C++ (in shared region)?

Tags: php, c++, boost

I have written one map (key, value) using C++, Boost library in shared region.

```
void CreateIndexMap()
{
    shared_memory_object::remove(Getsharedmemoryregion());
    managed_shared_memory segment(create_only,Getsharedmemoryregion(), 10000000);
    void_allocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());
    complex_map_type *mymap = segment.construct<complex_map_type>("MyMap")(std::less<char_string>(), alloc_inst);             
}
```

**Creating memory map in shared region:**

```
void UpdateIndexMap(std::string str, std::string index, const char* SharedMemory)
 {
    managed_shared_memory segment(open_only,SharedMemory);
    void_allocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());
    complex_map_type *mymap = segment.find<complex_map_type>("MyMap").first;
    std::string h = ConvertTolowercase(str);
    char_string patternvalue(h.c_str(), alloc_inst);
    char_string indexvalue((index).c_str(), alloc_inst);  
    mymap->insert(std::pair<char_string, char_string>(patternvalue,indexvalue));
 }
```

Now I am developing one web application using PHP and want to read map in shared region to get the data. How to implement it?

Comment: You need implement that in C++ and expose an extension module to PHP. In other words, separate your concerns better, because you don't want to be doing this (instead, e.g. make a networked API that you can use from PHP?). In case you are curious still: http://www.php-cpp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Ah, just noticed [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088913/error-while-accessing-boost-interprocess-shared-memory-region-using-apache-web-i) was also by you.

You **really** do not want to complicate the matter by trying to embed the C++ code directly into PHP.

It is bound to be *far* simpler to find out why the child process spawned from a PHP page doesn't allow you to access shared memory. In the worst possible case, make the process very secure and just **[call `setuid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid)** to force it to impersonate a certain user (assuming a UNIX-flavoured host). Do **not** setuid to root (this is a security no-no).